# I want to free last 3 bytes of 4 byte allocated data (the data is not an array it is one single integer)

Tags: c++, c, realloc

I am using realloc function for this purpose but it is not certainly returning the same memory address as my first allocated location.

```
void *vp1 = realloc(vp, 1);
```

I want vp1 is always equal to vp.

**Edit:**

I am actually trying to flag my destroyed objects with using their first byte, and free rest of the memory.

Comment: In that case the best thing is to not `realloc` the pointer. Unless memory is tight, just leave the excess 3 bytes be.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck It is not the case, I tried to simplify the problem to explain it more easily. I actually have big structures and I am trying to squeze them.

Comment: Are you really intersted in CPP? It may have other solutions.

Comment: Freeing 3 bytes is not really useful, what problem are you _actually_ trying to resolve. Is this an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: You may need to design your own heap manager.  The one that comes with your standard C/C++ library probably doesn't have the granularity of 1 byte allocations.  Implementations for heap management have a lot of liberty for the behavior details, performance, and "waste".

Comment: @MichealWalz I want to flag destroyed big objects with using its first byte. I think I explained better :)

Comment: It sounds even more now like you want your own allocator... Or like it is not even XY-problem, but XYZ-problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am actually going to write that code into global delete operator. I don't want to make my own allocator. It will make the system more complex. I want to solve my problem with regular c/c++ libraries.

Comment: Why the "I want vp1 is always equal to vp." requirement?  Simply assign `vp1` as follows `vp1 = realloc(vp, 1); if (vp1 == NULL) vp1 = vp;`

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there is no such guarantee provided by C standard.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5 (*emphasis mine*)

> The `realloc` function returns a pointer to the new object **(which may have the same
>   value as a pointer to the old object)**, or a null pointer if the new object could not be
>   allocated.

It mentions that, the newly returned pointer "may" point to the old location (with resized memory boundary as requested), but not guaranteed.

Comment: Likewise in [Linux realloc(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc): `realloc(ptr, size)` "returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory, which ... **may be different from `ptr`**" (emphasis added).

Comment: @cxw you mean man page? The standard is more authoritative, anyway.

Comment: Agreed.  In this case, the man page more clearly says "may be different," so requires less interpretation than the standard's "may have the same value".  In my personal experience, less-experienced askers sometimes find the man-page language easier to understand than the standardese.

Comment: @cxw Well, i'm not against you. :)

Comment: "realloc" function is not the solution it is certain, I am looking for a way to do this, somehow.

Comment: @wArtist question is, why?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I want to flag destroyed big objects with using its first byte. I think I explained better :) (Same comment as above.)

Comment: @wArtist what's the use? Are you trying to create some sort of memory analyzer or something? If yes, there are other better ways to do that. Otherwise, I don't see much merit in the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

1. C does not make any guarantees about particulars of how `malloc`, `realloc`, and `free` work. An implementation might or might not make released memory available for other use, and implementations generally do not provide byte-by-byte guarantees of how they work. They might make broad statements about whether significant amounts of memory are reused, returned to the operating system, et cetera.
2. The difference between one byte and four bytes is trivial. Do not worry about it. The data structures involved in managing memory generally use more space than that per allocation.
3. Generally, the fact that `realloc` returns a different address does not mean it did not release the memory for other use. In fact, some methods of managing memory may use different techniques for different sizes. Whole pages may be managed by requesting them from the operating system and releasing them back to the operating system, while medium-size allocations may be managed inside the process with linked lists and additional data structures, and tiny allocations might be managed with a bitmap. So requesting a smaller size could require releasing an allocation back to the pool of memory for one class of size and allocating new memory from the pool for the smaller size.

I would be skeptical that the last is what is happening with your reallocation of four bytes to one, except that, if it is not the explanation, it seems inefficient for your memory manager to bother changing the allocation. If you have four and want one and it does not actually manage those separately, then the practical solution would be simply to leave the entire allocation unchanged. Almost anything other than a bitmap for which bytes are allocated must use more than one byte to keep track of one-byte allocations.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when trying to realloc large sizes of memory, the realloc function will move all the data to a new alloc'd space, so you end losing all references from the previous block other than the pointer being realloc'd - which is a big problem if you have other pointers pointing to that structure.

And as pointed out by other answers, the realloc function is flagged as "undefined behaviour", good programming practices says you should always avoid using realloc and instead make your own functions to move the data consistently within the memory.